# Java function ending after time has elapsed

Tags: java, timer

Here's what I want to do. Given a function

```
public void foo() {

}
```

I would like to have it end after certain time has elapsed. That is, imagine this is some kind of random generator which has to produce random objects that satisfy some difficult constraints and hence it may or may not succeed under a given time allotment. That is, the function may actually be something like this

```
public void foo() {
   //task1
   while(fails) {
     //...
   }

   //task2
   while(fails2) {
      //...
   }

   //more tasks may follow, which use the data from the previous tasks to further try to satisfy difficult conditions
}
```

That is simply just an example. But the point is that the function consists of many while loops, many test cases, and lots of heavy computation.

**The goal:** I want to be able to say "run foo() and if 4 seconds has elapsed and foo() is still not done, then stop foo() immediately."

**What I have tried:** I have tried to include conditions on just about every line of foo() to see how much time has elapsed and to return out of the function if the 4 seconds has passed. But given how complicated foo() is, this is clearly very difficult to do code wise because this requires testing the time on every single line of the function.

**My thought logic:** I think this should be possible because there are functions that do this sort of thing, that terminate code regardless of the state, such as System.exit(1). That is the idea. I'd like to be able to call, from the outside, to have this function foo() terminate.

Comment: smells like you need TimerTask.

Comment: sounds about right. I've never used that. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// foo method and global variables used
private static ArrayList<Integer> foo() {
    // info class
    class Info {
        public boolean run, completed;
        public ArrayList<Integer> list;
    }
    // declare info object, list
    final Info info = new Info();
    final Object wait = new Object();
    // run a new thread
    Thread t = new Thread(
        new Runnable() {
            // run method
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // setup run
                info.run = true;
                info.completed = false;
                info.list = new ArrayList<>();
                // loop to modify list. Don't put a big piece of code that will
                // take a long time to execute in here. 
                while(info.run) {
                    // example of what you should be doing in here:
                    info.list.add(1);
                    // and if you are done modifying the list, use:
                    break;
                }
                // done modifying list
                info.completed = true;
                synchronized(wait) {
                    wait.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    );
    t.start();
    // wait for four seconds, then return list
    try {
        synchronized(wait) {
            wait.wait(4000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    info.run = false;
    return info.completed ? info.list : null;
}
// main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get list
    ArrayList<Integer> list = foo();
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

What the foo() method does?

1. Begins to modify the list it will eventually return
2. If the time took modifying this list exceeds four seconds, it will stop modifying the list and return the list.
3. It will return null if the list was stopped early.
4. It now only uses local variables!
5. Nice bonus, it will immediately return the list the second modifying it is done.

Comment: @CodeGuy Yeah, it's pretty messy, I just wrote this up in two minutes.

Comment: How can I get it so that I know explicitely if foo() has not finished. Right now, it prints that foo is stopped everytime.

Comment: Please see edits. I need foo() to return an ArrayList, not void. I added code where I would initialize it and where I would modify it and return it. How can I do that?

Comment: I think it will require some custom classes.

Comment: @CodeGuy I don't think what I just put up works anyway. Let me try this again.

Comment: Couldn't the list still end up being manipulated by that thread after it returns?

Comment: Also...I would like to have the ArrayList be null if it did not finish.

Comment: @CodeGuy Yes, I think what I have done here works fine. The list will stop being manipulated by the thread once the method returns.

Comment: Perfect. And what about having the arraylist be null if it didn't finish in time?

Comment: can "run" and "completed" be declared inside of foo() somehow?

Comment: haha, nice fix. Also, is it possible that I initialize "list" inside that while(run) loop? how can we get that working?

Comment: (imagine this is not an array list but is some object which requires the output of the difficult computation to construct it)

Answer (score 2):

Submit it as a runnable to an executor service and call get on the returned future with the desired timeout. Then in the catch block for the timeout exception you can cancel the future.

*EDIT: Code sample*

```
import com.google.common.base.Throwables;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ExecutorExample {
  private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  public void example() {
    Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
      @Override
      public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Do your complicated stuff";
      }
    });

    try {
      future.get(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Throwables.propagate(e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      //handle
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      future.cancel(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I'll give this a try. But first, what is this "Throwables" stuff. Is that necessary?

Comment: Not necessary, you can do whatever you want in the other catch blocks. I just have a habit of propagating exceptions I don't want to handle.

Comment: Gotcha. So I ran this and it just seemed to run without stopping (until I manually terminated the program) or printing anything.

Comment: You will also need to check Thread.interrupted() periodically in your tasks and throw an InterruptedException once it returns true.

Comment: Hmmm...so this doesn't avoid the need to manually check (just as I suggested doing with the time elapsed in my original question).

Comment: I think this is a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do the trick, but beware:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Runnable fooRunner = new Runnable(){ public void run(){
        foo();
    }

    Thread fooThread = new Thread(fooRunner);
    fooThread.start();

    Thread.sleep(4000);

    fooThread.stop(); //warning -- this is deprecated!
}
```

The problem is that [`Thread.stop` is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29).

Multi-threading in Java is fundamentally a *cooperative* endeavor.  Because `foo()` may be manipulating shared state, probably protected by a lock that it currently owns, stopping it at an arbitrary point is potentially very dangerous and could lead to unpredictable failures, bugs, etc. later on in the program.  (Indeed, since `foo`'s return type is `void`, it *must* manipulate some shared state at some point in order to store its result.)

The language does provide a way to tell a thread that it should stop at the next convenient point: [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29), [`Thread.interrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29), and [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html).  Your `foo()` method does need to check whether it's been interrupted periodically; that's the way it's done, and any higher-level library constructs (like [`Future.cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29)) rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

You must enter into the hellish arena of writing threaded code.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Pseudo code (mutableboolean available in apache commons http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi)

```
...
final MutableBoolean finished = new MutableBoolean(false);
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        doComplicatedStuff(finished);
    }
}).start();

Thread.sleep(4000);
finished.setValue(true);
```

Comment: I'm actually somewhat familar with Threads. I've made Runnable classes and threads. Could you try to give me an example of how this can be done with concurency?

Comment: Sure.  Cracks knuckles.  Do not copy and paste this code. :) *goes to edit answer*

Comment: Well...I don't necessarily want to System.exit(0) at that point, I just want to end doComplicatedStuff() method....can the code you posted be adapted for that?

Comment: You could pass the finished variable to doComplicatedStuff method and check it every now and then, and instead of looping on the finished state, just sleep four seconds and then change it to true.

Comment: the computer really doesn't mind checking a variable constantly.  I think they secretly like it.  What's the primary concern of checking the variable?

Comment: The concern is that it does not necessarily fix the problem. It just changes the problem to require checking a boolean rather than a time. It is essentially still the same thing I discussed in the attempt at a solution in the question I posted.